# Sum a subset of of numbers in a list

Tags: kotlin

Is there a way in Kotlin for doing the `sum()` operation on a *filtered* list of numbers, without actually filtering out the elements first?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
val nums = listOf<Long>(-2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4)
val sum = nums.sum(it > 0)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can make use of `Iterable<T>.sumBy`:

```
/**
 * Returns the sum of all values produced by [selector] function applied to each element in the collection.
 */
public inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.sumBy(selector: (T) -> Int): Int {
    var sum: Int = 0
    for (element in this) {
        sum += selector(element)
    }
    return sum
}
```

You can pass a function to it where the function transforms negative value to 0. So, it sums up all values in the list which is greater than 0 since adding 0 makes no effect to the result.

```
val nums = listOf<Long>(-2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4)
val sum = nums.sumBy { if (it > 0) it.toInt() else 0 }
println(sum)    //10
```

If you require a `Long` value back, you have to write an extension for `Long` just like [`Iterable<T>.sumByDouble`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.1.3/libraries/stdlib/src/generated/_Collections.kt#L1762).

```
inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.sumByLong(selector: (T) -> Long): Long {
    var sum: Long = 0
    for (element in this) {
        sum += selector(element)
    }
    return sum
}
```

Then, the `toInt()` conversion can be taken away.

```
 nums.sumByLong { if (it > 0) it else 0 }
```

As suggested by @Ruckus T-Boom, `if (it > 0) it else 0` can be simplified using `Long.coerceAtLeast()` which returns the value itself or the given minimum value:

```
nums.sumByLong { it.coerceAtLeast(0) }
```

Comment: You can use `it.coerceAtLeast(0)` instead of `if (it > 0) it else 0`

Answer (score 1):

```
data class Product(val name: String, val quantity: Int) {
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val productList = listOf(
            Product("A", 100),
            Product("B", 200),
            Product("C", 300)
    )

    val totalPriceInList1: Int = productList.map { it.quantity }.sum()
    println("sum(): " + totalPriceInList1)

    val totalPriceInList2: Int = productList.sumBy { it.quantity }
    println("sumBy(): " + totalPriceInList2)
}
```

this is the result of our code

```
sum(): 600
sumBy(): 600
```

Answer (score 1):

[sumBy](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sum-by.html) and [sumByDouble](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sum-by-double.html) are **`Deprecated`** from kotlin `1.5` . You can check those link.

Use [sumOf](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sum-of.html) to get sum on a `List` or `Array`

`sumOf`

> Returns the sum of all values produced by selector function applied to each element in the collection or Array.

Example:

```
data class Order(
  val id : String,
  val price : Double
) 

val orderList = ......
val sum = orderList.sumOf { it.price }
```